# Are cyclical dependencies between microservices an anti-pattern?

Tags: microservices

Say I have a `user-accounts` service and a `profiles` service. If the `profiles` service requires data from the `user-accounts` service for certain computations that means the `profiles` service depends on the `user-accounts` service.

Now, say additional functionality is being implemented for the `user-accounts` service. This functionality requires data from the `profiles` service.

This would create a cyclical dependency as each service depends on the other. Is this considered harmful?

What are some alternatives to introducing a cyclical dependency between microservices? Would it be best to add an *additional* service to serve as a broker?

Answer (score 1):

I would try to avoid this scenario. Personally I try to avoid coupling microservices altogether and rely more on orchestration and/or event choreography.

Here are some ways that you might be able to avoid it:

1. Combine `user-accounts` and `profiles` as a single microservice. If they're closely related, perhaps you have your service granularity slightly wrong.
2. Create a higher-level orchestration layer that orchestrates calls between `user-accounts` and `profiles`.
3. Depending on your specific scenario, you might be able to choreograph events between `user-accounts` and `profiles`. One service might publish events, while the other service is subscribed to these events. You can use a message broker like RabbitMQ in this type of architecture.

There's no absolute right answer IMO - these are just some general guidelines - it really depends on your specific scenario...

Comment: I agree it is context dependent. The situation might naturally emerge from bounded contexts, each service having a different view on an entity and maybe adding information they require. However, make sure that each attribute has not multiple writing services, that would be an anti-pattern. In general, start with coarse-grained services and become more fine-grained if there is real need to.

Comment: I wasn't familiar with the term "orchestration" in this context, I will do some reading. As far as your suggestion regarding event choreography, what about if some operation is synchronous? Ex. if the client wants to get the result of an API call that depends on two different services.